# Object/Material is infront of Camera

Tags: openinventor

I have start working with openinventor. I have a socube in viewer. I would like to check if socube is infront of camera or not. So when I move cube somewhere away from camera view value should be false.

```
SoSeparator root = new SoSeparator(); 
SoMaterial Material = new SoMaterial(); 
Material.diffuseColor.SetValue(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red 
root.AddChild(Material); 
root.AddChild(new SoCone()); 
viewer = new SoWinExaminerViewer(this); 
viewer.SetTitle("Example 1.1 .NET"); 
viewer.SetSceneGraph(root); 
viewer.ViewAll();
```

Now I want to add a behavior something like if I move cone away from camera it returns false

Comment: Show the code you've tried and specifically where you're having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that Open Inventor does not provide a method that implements this query. However it is possible to write one using information you *can* query.

If you can accept an approximately correct answer, then your goal is to answer the question: Does the bounding box of the geometry intersect the view frustum?
Get the bounding box using SoGetBoundingBoxAction, then get the current view volume parameters from the current camera, e.g. viewer->getCamera()->getViewVolume().